# What is the benefit of using asymmetric LDA prior?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am reading the paper [Rethinking LDA: Why Priors Matter](http://dirichlet.net/pdf/wallach09rethinking.pdf). The author claims that the combination of asymmetric prior for document-topic proportion and symmetric prior for topic-word is the best, comparing to symmetric + symmetric; symmetric+asymmetric; asymmetric+asymmetric.

What I don't understand is why? What benefit does this asymmetric prior bring? After all, a symmetric prior is imposed on the asymmetric prior.

Answer (score 1):

It just seems to fit the data better. The prior is nothing more than an assumption about your data of how the topics are actually distributed and I think for most cases it absolutely makes sense to assume that there are documents that cover more topics and such that cover less.
Whereas for the topic-word distribution they explain in the Discussion (section 7) why it is a bad idea to assume it to be asymmetric:

> A priori, we therefore do not expect that a particular topic’s distribution over words will be
>   like that of any other topic. An asymmetric prior over Φ is therefore a bad idea: the base measure
>   will reflect corpus-wide word usage statistics, and a priori, all topics will exhibit those statistics too.